# Ethereum Wallet Version 0.7.6 Couldn't connect to node

Tags: mist, wallets, windows

[image]

Hello, 
Sometimes Ethereum Wallet gets this error when I want to start up. I have Windows 7 x64. What is the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Does that happen everytime you launch the wallet?

Comment: Sometimes, not everytime.